# Electronic devices on EU flights: tablet, e-reader and bluetooth noise cancelling headphones allowed?

Tags: air-travel, europe, electronic-items

I will be flying from Antwerp International in Belgium to Alicante International in about 3 weeks on a Tui Fly airplane, and I was wondering about the dos and don'ts of using electronic devices on this flight. In particular, i'm wondering about the following:

1. Using bluetooth noise cancelling headphones ([Philips TAH9550](https://www.download.p4c.philips.com/files/t/tah9505bk_00/tah9505bk_00_dfu_eng.pdf)) during the entire flight, including takeoff and landing, which do not have separate power states for bluetooth and noise cancelling: I can either turn both BT and NC on or both BT and NC off, or I can disable NC while keeping BT on, but I can't choose to only enable NC as far as I know.
2. Using a Kobo e-reader during the entire flight with wifi disabled to read ebooks (no bluetooth AFAIK).
3. Using an iPad mini from 2019, either cabled with the headphones or with bluetooth enabled between takeoff and landing to watch previously downloaded content digitally.

I know that these things have changed since the last time I have been aboard an airplane in 2012, but I do not know to what extent. I found some questions related to the USA, but it's possible EU rules may be different.

Comment: Note that irrespective of the electronics aspect, you are not supposed to wear headphones during take-off and landing, as you must be able to hear crew instructions.

Comment: @jcaron that's not a blanket rule, and I can't remember seeing that rule recently.

Comment: FWIW, I flew Condor from Germany to Egypt and back in October, and they had a Wifi-based inflight entertainment system. The instructions given were literally "connect to hotspot X, then visit website Y". So, "the phone/tablet needs to be in airplane mode all the time" definitely doesn't apply to every airline.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm you can turn on WIFI without disabling Airplane mode on most phones and tablets

Comment: I would be shocked if any of the devices mentioned is a problem, unless you bring a small generator to charge them with. I had my noise-cancelling headphones and Steam Deck complete with Dock, Keyboard, Powerbank and 45W charger and it wasn't a problem.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Airplane mode is for disabling the cellular radio, not the Wi-Fi. Some devices will also turn off Wi-Fi when you first enable airplane mode, but you can normally turn it back on immediately without disabling airplane mode if you so desire.

Comment: @MJeffryes I was told to take out my earbuds during takeoff and landing on an EasyJet flight from a couple of months ago. It’s still around.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's not easyJet policy, but there may be local law that requires that, or possibly just the flight crew prefer it, and certain landing conditions can also prevent the use of electronics. Per easyJet's policy 'We do ask that you remove headphones during the safety briefing'. As I say, it isn't a blanket rule that you can't use headphones during takeoff or landing, you just need to follow the flight crew's instructions. https://www.easyjet.com/en/help/boarding-and-flying/boarding-and-on-board-services

Comment: Bluetooth seems to be a particularly grey area on airlines. As it's short range and low power, I can see why some airlines permit it, the risk of a BT signal even being able to penetrate the cockpit is pretty remote. Some airlines now have BT modules in the seatback IFE so passengers can use their own headphones. And it's probably the hardest to police, can't tell just by looking if the headphones are using the BT radio or are just noise cancelling. You'd have to ban people from using wireless headphones entirely if you want to be sure, which is easier said than done with modern smartphones!

Answer (score 15):

Each airline has significantly different rules for the usage of electronic devices on board, so if you fly with TUI, you should observe their regulations. I can't find the corresponding page in English, but [here are TUI Fly's rules for usage of electronic devices on board in German](https://www.tui.com/service-kontakt/flug/elektronik-im-flugzeug), and these are the relevant parts for your questions:

- Electronic devices must not be used during the security briefing.
- Electronic devices with a radio transmitter or receiver (except bluetooth) must not be used if they do not have a 'flight mode' to disable the radio module.
- Smaller devices (e.g. smart phones, tablets, e-book readers, cameras) may be used during all phases of the flight.
- Larger devices (eg. laptops) must be stowed during take off and landing and can only be used when the plane has reached altitude.
- The crew may due to extraordinary circumstances further restrict the usage of electronic devices.

Which answers your questions as follows: You are allowed to use all the mentioned devices (bluetooth headphones included) during all phases of the flight except during the security briefing. Wi-fi must be disabled on your e-book reader at all times.

As jcaron mentions in his comment, it is indeed common that head phones are not allowed during take off and landing, but the TUI page I am linking to explicitely allows head phone usage 'during all phases of the flight'.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149988/discussion-on-answer-by-tor-einar-jarnbjo-electronic-devices-on-eu-flights-tabl); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.